# How solve InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: Detected at node 'mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is the code to create the model:

I'm having multiple errors while running this VGG training code (code and errors shown below). I don't know if its because of my dataset or is it something else.

```
# Definir el modelo
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Activation, Flatten, Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.losses import mean_absolute_error
model = Sequential()

# Agregar capas convolucionales
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(height, width, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Agregar capas totalmente conectadas
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))

# Compilar el modelo
#opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.001, decay=0.001/(30*0.5))
# Entrenar el modelo
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=["accuracy"])
callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5, monitor="val_loss", mode="min", restore_best_weights=True)]
    
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), callbacks=callbacks)
```

This is the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6eba740a4ec6> in <cell line: 132>()
    130     keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5, monitor="val_loss", mode="min", restore_best_weights=True)]
    131 
--> 132 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), callbacks=callbacks)
    133 
    134 # Implementar el modelo en una aplicación o programa

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference'
```

I'm running this on google colaboratory. Is there a module that I should install? Or is it purely an error on the code itself?

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem with the Tensorflow/ keras version. This code does not show any error when I tried replicating the given code. (Attaching the replicated code [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/0d621c70696af1b50f86aff7e1d9d7b7/76043755.ipynb) here).

However, Since this is an image classification model, you should try by changing the loss function to 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy' which computes the crossentropy loss between the labels and predictions.